# I have trouble adding more than one product-line to a cURL call when reading lines from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, loops, curl

I have a number of orders in a database, each order can have more than one orderline. 
I have to send each orderline in a curl-call, and I'm having trouble when I have more than one orderline.

I have tried a few different approaches, but can't seem to get it right.

Single line in cURL: 

`{
      "type": "physical",
      "reference": "9788205521186",
      "name": "Dvalen",
      "quantity": 1,
      "quantity_unit": "pcs",
      "unit_price": 1000,
      "tax_rate": 0,
      "total_amount": 1000,
      "total_tax_amount": 0
}`

Multiple lines should look like this:

```
{
    "reference": "9788205521186",
    "type": "Physical",
    "name": "Dvalen",
    "quantity": "1",
    "quantity_unit": "stk",
    "unit_price": "1000",
    "tax_rate": "0",
    "total_amount": "1000",
    "total_tax_amount": "0",
    "product_url": "https:\/\/www.hk.no\/bok\/I9788205521186",
    "image_url": "https:\/\/res.cloudinary.com\/image\/upload\/c_fit,q_auto:best,w_140\/9788205521186"
},
{
    "reference": "9788205521186",
    "type": "Physical",
    "name": "Dvalen",
    "quantity": "1",
    "quantity_unit": "stk",
    "unit_price": "1000",
    "tax_rate": "0",
    "total_amount": "1000",
    "total_tax_amount": "0",
    "product_url": "https:\/\/www.habok.no\/bok\/I9788205521186",
    "image_url": "https:\/\/res.cloudinary.com\/image\/upload\/c_fit,q_auto:best,w_140\/9788205521186"
}
```

Current code:

```
/Fetch orders from database.  
$sql_ordre = "SELECT * FROM ordre WHERE behandlet = '0'";
$data = mysqli_query($dbconnection, $sql_ordre) or die(mysqli_error($dbconnection));

while ($rad =  mysqli_fetch_array($data)){
    //For each order, fetch orderlines. 
    $klarnaid = $rad['klarnaid'];
    $sql_linje = "SELECT * FROM ordrelinje WHERE behandlet = '0' AND klarnaid = '$klarnaid'";
    $linjedata = mysqli_query($dbconnection,$sql_linje) or die (mysqli_error($dbconnection));

    //For each orderline, loop through and push to array:
    while ($linjerad = mysqli_fetch_array($linjedata)) {
        $orderline = array();
        array_push($orderline, [
            "reference" => "9788205521186",
            "type" => "Physical",
            "name" => "Dvalen",
            "quantity" => "1",
            "quantity_unit" => "stk",
            "unit_price" => "1000",
            "tax_rate" => "0",
            "total_amount" => "1000",
            "total_tax_amount" => "0",
            "product_url" => "https://www.url.no/bok/I9788205521186",
            "image_url" => "https://url.no/image/upload/c_fit,q_auto:best,w_140/9788205521186"
        ]);

        //Format to Json and ehco. 
        $orderline_json = json_encode($orderline, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        echo $orderline_json;
    }
}
```

This works just fine for one orderline, but as soon as I have more than one. I have trouble.

Comment: "I have trouble" is not a good problem statement. Please be more specific next time you post a question.

Comment: Thanks Dharman. I know this and I'm only processing my own, already sanitized data. I appriciate the comment though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are resetting `$orderline` on every iteration, and only last row from MySQL query makes it to the `$orderline_json`. Change order of lines like this:

```php
$orderline = array();
while ($linjerad = mysqli_fetch_array($linjedata)) {
array_push($orderline, [
// ... no changes below
```

Comment: Thanks. Total brainfart. I was stuck for way too long on this. Thank you so much :)